# JavaScript - jquery DataTable append button to row + click event

Tags: jquery, datatables

its possible to attach click event when datatable is building the rows?, with out calling external global function and finding the closes tr and getting DATA object?.

```
$('#example').DataTable({
     columns : [{
        title   : 'msg',
        sClass  : 'col-sm-2',
        render  : function(data, type, row){
            var b = $('<button>the button</button>').click(function(){
                alert(row.msg);
            })
            return b;
        }
     }],
     ajax:{
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'foo.php',
     }
});
```

i know the above example dosnt work, cos render function must return string, it just an example for what i need.

- create an element.
- attach click function passing 'row' object, with out calling global function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer, no you can't. I see you don't *want to*, but I would use a class and event delegation, like this:

```
var myDataTable=$('#example').DataTable({  // note the stored reference to the dataTable
     columns : [{
        title   : 'msg',
        sClass  : 'col-sm-2',
        render  : function(data, type, row){ 
            return '<button class="some-class">the button</button>';
        }
     }],
     ajax:{
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'foo.php',
     }
});


$(document).on('click', '.some-class', function(){ 
        var $btn=$(this);
        var $tr=$btn.closest('tr');
        var dataTableRow=myDataTable.row($tr[0]); // get the DT row so we can use the API on it
        var rowData=dataTableRow.data();
        console.log(rowData.msg);
});
```

---

*Technically* you could use the [`rowCallback` function](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) to attach the handler after each row is rendered, but you'd have to use `.find()` or similar to get back to the button and the approach outlined above is far cleaner IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

You can use "columns.createdCell" to get what you want:

```
$( '#example' ).DataTable( {
    columns         : [ {
        data        : 'msg',
        title       : 'msg',
        sClass      : 'col-sm-2',
        createdCell : function( td, cellData, rowData, row, col ){
            var b = $( '<button>the button</button>' ).click( function() {
                alert( rowData.msg );
            } );
            $( td ).html( b );
        }
    } ],
    // using data instead of ajax to demonstrate
    data            : [
        { msg       : 'Message 1!' },
        { msg       : 'Message 2!' },
        { msg       : 'Message 3!' }
    ],
    /*
    ajax            : {
        type        : 'POST',
        url         : 'foo.php',
    }
    */
} );
```

Just pass `b` to `$( td ).html()` and voilà!

Answer (score 0):

adding both blur then focus allow clicking and continue typing

```
if (dataTable.columns(colunIndex).search() !== e.value) {
    dataTable.columns(colunIndex)
        .search(e.value)
        .draw();
    $(this).blur();
    $(this).focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let  table = $('#table_patient_request').DataTable()
table.clear().draw();
const response = await   [1,3,4,5,6,7]

const items = response.map((resp,index) => {
  const item = [
    `<button type="button" id="exemplo_${index}" date-isconf="${resp.id}"  class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light ml-1 mr-1">exemplo</button>`
  ]

  table.row.add(item).draw()
  table.on('click', `#exemplo_${index}`, function (e) {
    alert('exemplo')
  });
});
```